# If ListView has fewer items(less than scrollable) still in Scrollbar place a white space is shown if android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset" is set

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I have a List View, I wanted the scroll bar to be seen outside of the List and touching on Scroll Bar should not send the click to the list items behind it, Hence I have set this attribute as below.

```
android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
```

This works fine as long as the list view has more items. However there is a problem if the list view has less number of items in which case scroll bar is not needed/not scrollable.
If there are few items say 2 items, then the List view is displayed with right side white padding which was the place for Scroll Bar.

How to remove this white space that Scroll bar is occupying if the list items are very few with "outsideInset" attribute being set?.

Comment: Why you want scroll bar. Because listview already provides scrolling functionality if item size increases. You don't need having additional scroll for it.

Comment: I am not adding any additional scroll bar here, I am just defining the way scroll bar will be displayed in List view by setting it to "outsideInset". And I am expecting this Scrol bar not to occupy any space if the number of items are less than scrolable area

Answer (score 0):

Try disable over scroll:

```
listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

for hide the scroll bars:

```
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

**Note:** if your list size doesn't exceeded the screen size then it shouldn't be able to scroll.

Comment: It still shows White space in the place of Scroll Bar if the list size doesn't exceed the screen size

Comment: @Guna -  will you please post your xml code of list View and its list Item

Comment: @Guna - Will you Please also mention which api You are working.